# Jquery UI MENU focus don't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menu

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>menu demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-     ui.css">
<style>
.ui-menu {
width: 200px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
<li id="item3"><a href="#">Item 3</a>
<ul>
  <li ><a href="#">Item 3-1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3-4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3-5</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
  $( "#menu" ).menu();

  $("#menu").menu("focus",null, $("#menu").menu().find("#item3"));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I use the focus as the api said, it focused on the item-3 menu , but it didn't open its sub-menu, is there anything wrong with my code , somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra menu from:

```
$("#menu").menu("focus",null, $("#menu").menu().find("#item3"));
```

i.e:

```
$("#menu").menu("focus",null, $("#menu").find("#item3"));
```

here's a working demo: http://liveweave.com/y3FYnm

Comment: Better yet, the menu should have been instantiated previously and therefore a cachable reference should have been created. `var menu = $('#menu').menu()` and then `menu.find('#item3');`

Comment: Fair enough, be well.

Comment: It works in the i.e, but when it still can not open sub-menu in the chrome, any suggestion?

Comment: The demo works fine on chrome, just tested it - make sure that you don't have javascript disabled from the developer tools.

Comment: Really? I copied the code and save it as html file then open it in the chrome , it didn't work at all , even there is no css style . My chrome version is 31.0.1650.57 .

Comment: open the file in chrome, press F12 and go to the 'console' tab. refresh the page and tell me if it says anything

Comment: well ,it says  failed to load the resource:http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-%20%20%20%20%20ui.css and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js, the first I have resolved , the second I don't know how to sove